# jQuery - Como adicionar evento ao controle após o carregamento do DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Preciso adicionar um teclado virtual após uma validação no codebehind. O controle fica invisível até que essa validação seja verdadeira.

Quando adiciono o teclado virtual com o controle já visível na tela, funciona 100%. Após a validação não está funcionado.

Os scripts utilizados são:

```
<link href="../../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<link href="../../css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="../../js/jquery.keyboard.js"></script>    
<link href="../../keyboard/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="../../keyboard/demo.js"></script>
<script src="http://mottie.github.com/Jatt/js/jquery.jatt.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../../keyboard/jquery.chili-2.2.js"></script> 
<script src="../../keyboard/recipes.js"></script>
```

O controle que está recebendo o teclado virtual é:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailCliente" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

O código que faz o teclado virtual aparecer no controle está no arquivo demo.js e o código segue abaixo:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    var configAlpha = {
        display: {
            'bksp': '\u2190',
            'accept': 'Concluido',
            'default': 'ABC',
            'shift': '\u21d1',
            'meta1': '.?123',
            'meta2': '#+='
        },
        layout: 'custom',
        customLayout: {
            'default': [
                'q w e r t y u i o p {bksp}',
                'a s d f g h j k l {enter}',
                '{s} z x c v b n m , . {s}',
                '{meta1} {space} {meta1} {accept}'
            ],
            'shift': [
                'Q W E R T Y U I O P {bksp}',
                'A S D F G H J K L {enter}',
                '{s} Z X C V B N M ! ? {s}',
                '{meta1} {space} {meta1} {accept}'
            ],
            'meta1': [
                '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 {bksp}',
                '- / : ; ( ) \u20ac & @ {enter}',
                '{meta2} . , ? ! \' " {meta2}',
                '{default} {space} {default} {accept}'
            ],
            'meta2': [
                '[ ] { } # % ^ * + = {bksp}',
                '_ \\ | ~ < > $ \u00a3 \u00a5 {enter}',
                '{meta1} . , ? ! \' " {meta1}',
                '{default} {space} {default} {accept}'
            ]
        }
    };      

    $('#txtEmailCliente').keyboard(configAlpha);    
});
```

Alguém poderia me dizer como faço para que após clicar em um determinado botão, fazer uma validação e dar txtEmailCliente.Visible = true esse teclado virtual apareça?

Eu teria que fazer o bind do evento ao controle de alguma forma, alguém sabe como?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode realizar essa validação do lado do servidor através de por exemplo, um botão.

```
<input id="foo" runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="ex_OnClick" />
```

do lado do servidor você então criaria o método:

```
protected void ex_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//validacao e em seguida o seu txtEmailCliente.Visible = true

}
```

Comment: Lucas, o problema não está em como fazer a validação, isso está tranquilo. O que quero fazer é adicionar o teclado virtual ao controle após essa validação. Teria que ser algo via jQuery eu penso.

Comment: A sua textbox está sendo rodada também do lado do servidor, por tanto também pode ser manipulada por lá e seta-la para visivel, ao meu ver a unica coisa faltante seria colocar a tag visible no seu textbox para começar por default como não visivel: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailCliente" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Lucas, você não entendeu o meu problema, de qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

achei a solução para o meu problema. Quando ocorria um post parcial no AJAX PANEL, o código abaixo estava perdendo as classes do CSS.

```
$('#txtEmailCliente').keyboard(configAlpha);
```

Fiz uma alteração para que o DOM não perdesse a propriedade CSS do controle conforme abaixo:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#txtEmailCliente', {}, function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).keyboard(configAlpha)
})
```

Dessa forma, mesmo que faça o post no formulário, ao receber o focus, o controle irá exibir o teclado virtual.

Espero poder ter ajudado com a minha dúvida, mas tive que pesquisar e colocar a solução para vocês.